# Compare two List elements and replace if id is equals

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists with Classes

```
public class Product 
{
  int id;
  string url;
  ect.
}
```

I need compare in the old list (10k+ elements) a new list(10 elements) by ID
and if an id is same just replace data from new List to old list

I think it will be good using LINQ.
Can you help me how can I use LINQ or there are batter library?

Comment: what does this have to do with `Android`?

Comment: You have the 10k+ list in memory? No datastore?

Comment: I just hope you do not think that iterating through 10k elements with a LINQ keeping that ammount of data constantly in memory is a good idea.

Comment: It's better you write a sql function or strore procedure for that and call it from ef! Since irritating over 10k element takes many time

Comment: Worst case to help, make your 10k collection a dictionary. Then just find them by id so you don't need to iterate the whole collection. Best case of all, patch the database with the new information.

Comment: I second @Everts ' comment.

Comment: 10k+ it for example.
Android: it will build the app for Android using Unity3D
Can somebody write code for example?

Comment: @Everts, only downside of making the collection a dictionary is if the collection relies on it's ordering.

Comment: @BobVale How about SortedDictionary?

Comment: But all in all, it is a really bad design to download all the data then modify few of them and then upload them back on db. Normal way would be to send a Patch or Post request where the json contains the new entries. No more. Then the server takes care of finding those entries and update them. But the current design is really wrong and likely to show its limitations any time.

Comment: @everts that relies on a sortkey. It all depends if the collect needs to maintain insert order

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to modify the collection in place or return a new collection?

If you are returning a new collection you could

```
var query = from x in oldItems
            join y in newItems on y.Id equals x.Id into g
            from z in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select z ?? x;
var new List = query.ToList();
```

This method will ignore entries in newItems that do not exist in old items.

If you are going to be modifying the collection in place  you would be better off working with a dictionary and referencing that everywhere.

You can create a dictionary from the list by doing

```
var collection = items.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x);
```

Note modifying the dictionary doesn't alter the source collection, the idea is to replace your collection with the dictionary object.

If you are using the dictionary you can then iterate over new collection and check the key.

```
foreach (var item in newItems.Where(x => collection.ContainsKey(x.Id))) {
  collection[item.Id] = item;
}
```

Dictionaries are iterable so you can loop over the Values collection if you need to.  Adds and removes are fast because you can reference by key.  The only problem I can think you may run into is if you rely on the ordering of the collection.

If you are stuck needing to use the original collection type then you could use the ToDictionary message on your newItems collection.  This makes your update code look like this.

```
var converted = newItems.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x);
for (var i = 0; i < oldItems.Count(); i++) {
  if (converted.ContainsKey(oldItems[i].Id)) {
    oldItems[i] = converted[oldItems[i].Id];
  }
}
```

This has the advantage the you only need to loop the newitems collection once, from then on it's key lookups, so it's less cpu intensive.  The downside is you've created an new collection of keys for newitems so it consumes more memory.

Comment: `foreach (var i = 0; i < oldItems.Count(); i++)` ??

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var product in newList)
{
  int index = oldList.FindIndex(x => x.id == product.id);
  if (index != -1)
   {
     oldList[index].url = product.url;
   }
}
```

This will work and i think it's a better solution too. 
All the above solution are creating new object in memory and creating new list with 10k+ 
records is definitely a bad idea.
Please make fields in product as it won't be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Send you a sample function that joins the two list by id property of both lists and then update original Product.url with the newer one

```
void ChangeItems(IList<Product> original, IList<Product> newer){      
    original.Join(newer, o => o.id, n => n.id, (o, n) => new { original = o, newer = n })
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(j => j.original.Url = j.newer.Url);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Solution :-*** : The `LINQ` solution you're look for will be something like this

```
oldList = oldList.Select(ele => { return (newList.Any(i => i.id == ele.id) ? newList.FirstOrDefault(newObj => newObj.id == ele.id) : ele); }).ToList();
```

***Note :-***  Here we are creating the `OldList` based on `NewList` & `OldList` i.e we are replacing OldList `object` with NewList `object`.If you only want some of the new List properties you can create a copy Method in your class

EG for copy constructor

```
 oldList = oldList.Select(ele => { return (newList.Any(i => i.id == ele.id) ? ele.Copy(newList.FirstOrDefault(newObj => newObj.id == ele.id)) : ele); }).ToList();

//Changes in your class
public void Copy(Product prod)
{
    //use req. property of prod. to be replaced the old class 
    this.id = prod.id;
}
```

***Read***

> It is not a good idea to iterate over 10k+ elements even using linq as such it will still affect your `CPU performance`*

[Online sample for 1st solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lSAJOl)

Answer (score 0):

As you have class

```
public class Product
{
    public int id;
    public string url;
    public string otherData;
    public Product(int id, string url, string otherData)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.url = url;
        this.otherData = otherData;
    }
    public Product ChangeProp(Product newProd)
    {
        this.url = newProd.url;
        this.otherData = newProd.otherData;
        return this;
    }
}
```

**Note that**, now we have `ChangeProp` method in data class, this method will accept new class and modify old class with properties of new class and return modified new class (as you want your old class be replaced with new classes property (data). So at the end `Linq` will be readable and clean.

and you already have `oldList` with lots of entries, and have to replace data of oldList by data of newList if id is same, you can do it like below.

suppose they are having data like below,

```
    List<Product> oldList = new List<Product>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        oldList.Add(new Product(i, "OldData" + i.ToString(), "OldData" + i.ToString() + "-other"));
    }
    List<Product> newList = new List<Product>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        newList.Add(new Product(i, "NewData" + i.ToString(), "NewData" + i.ToString() + "-other"));
    }
```

this `Linq` will do your work.

```
    oldList.Where(x => newList.Any(y => y.id == x.id))
        .Select(z => oldList[oldList.IndexOf(z)].ChangeProp(newList.Where(a => a.id == z.id).FirstOrDefault())).ToList();
```